# TypeError session() - passing one argument but Python thinks I'm passing two

Tags: python, session, neo4j, arguments, typeerror

I'm getting this error in Python when trying to communicate to a Neo4j browser:

```
session = driver.session("WRITE")
TypeError: session() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Does anyone know why it's showing an error for two arguments when there is only one?

Comment: What is `driver`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to write using a session, I don't believe there is a need to add arguments. The extra argument provided is just `self` which is implied. Most of the docs reference using `with` to open and automatically close the session as needed, with the `write_transaction()` function to do any writing:

```
with driver.session() as session:
    session.write_transaction(add_friend, "Arthur", "Guinevere")
    session.write_transaction(add_friend, "Arthur", "Lancelot")
    session.write_transaction(add_friend, "Arthur", "Merlin")
    session.read_transaction(print_friends, "Arthur")
```

source: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver

Answer (score 0):

`session()` is a method in the Driver class. [It is defined the source as](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/blob/e42bc6a3f6036d8f4a2cd08a78cf27932b429575/neo4j/_sync/driver.py#L285):

```python
    def session(self, **config):
        ...
```

The method takes one positional argument, `self`, and then only accepts keyword arguments, `**config`. Python will automatically pass `self` as the first positional argument. So when you call it with:

```python
driver.session("WRITE")
```

You are calling `session()` with 2 positional arguments, `self` and `"WRITE"`, which is why you are getting the error, `TypeError: session() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Take a look at the Neo4j Python driver documentation for usage:

https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#session-construction

You can read more about `self` in the python docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=self#random-remarks